# getting exception unread result found and also not sble to stop scanning

Tags: python, sql, mysql, tkinter, opencv

I am working on a program to decode scanned qr code/ 2d data matrix code and store it in db in json string format and also let user to view user to data on the screen. Here in my code I am having two issues.

1. Whenever I run my code I get exception **Unread result found**. Here my db is already connected. This error also comes when I perform search operation or scan the image and it is getting stored in db.
2. The other issue it when i have to stop the streaming to capture images I have given **Stop scanning** button to user but it doesn't work. But when I press " **q** " the capturing stops and after that I press stop button which enables **start scanning** button to let enabled again. But it should directly work on **stop scanning** button.

Here is the code given below:

```
import cv2
import json
import mysql.connector
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar
import pylibdmtx.pylibdmtx as pylibdmtx

class QRCodeScanner:
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn
        self.decoder = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
        self.table_name = 'qr_codes2'
        self.create_table_if_not_exists()
        
    def create_table_if_not_exists(self):
        try:
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT 1 FROM {self.table_name} LIMIT 1")
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            self.create_table()
        else:
            print(f"Table '{self.table_name}' already exists.")

    def create_table(self):
        cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        query = f"""
        CREATE TABLE {self.table_name} (
            id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            data LONGTEXT NOT NULL
        )
        """
        cursor.execute(query)
        self.conn.commit()
        print(f"Table '{self.table_name}' created successfully.")
        cursor.close()

    def start(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

        if not cap.isOpened():
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "The webcam is not connected.")
            print("The webcam is not connected.")
            return

        while scanning and stop_button["state"] == NORMAL:
            ret, frame = cap.read()

            if not ret:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "The webcam is not working properly.")
                print("The webcam is not working properly.")
                break

            decoded_objects_qr = pyzbar.decode(frame)
            decoded_objects_dm = pylibdmtx.decode(frame)

            for decoded_object in decoded_objects_qr:
                data = decoded_object.data.decode()
                barcode_type = decoded_object.type

                print(barcode_type)
                
                if barcode_type == "QRCODE":
                    print("QR code detected:", data)
                else:
                    print("Unknown barcode type detected:", barcode_type)

                json_data = json.dumps(data)

                if json_data and json_data != '''""''':
                    try:
                        cursor = self.conn.cursor(buffered=True)
                        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO {self.table_name} (data) VALUES (%s)", (json_data,))
                        self.conn.commit()
                        print("Barcode data inserted into the database.")
                        retrieve_records()
                    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
                        print(f"An error occurred while inserting the data: {err}")
                        self.conn.rollback()
                else:
                    print("Empty barcode data. Skipped inserting into the database.")

            for decoded_object in decoded_objects_dm:
                data = decoded_object.data.decode()

                print("2D data matrix code detected:", data)

                json_data = json.dumps(data)

                if json_data and json_data != '''""''':
                    try:
                        cursor = self.conn.cursor(buffered=True)
                        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO {self.table_name} (data) VALUES (%s)", (json_data,))
                        self.conn.commit()
                        print("2D data matrix data inserted into the database.")
                        retrieve_records()
                    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
                        print(f"An error occurred while inserting the data: {err}")
                        self.conn.rollback()
                else:
                    print("Empty 2D data matrix data. Skipped inserting into the database.")

            cv2.imshow("Barcode Scanner", frame)

            key = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if key == ord('q'):
                break

        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    def close(self):
        self.conn.close()


def start_scanning():
    global scanning
    scanning = True
    start_button.configure(state=DISABLED)
    stop_button.configure(state=NORMAL)
    scanner.start()

def stop_scanning():
    global scanning
    scanning = False
    start_button.configure(state=NORMAL)
    stop_button.configure(state=DISABLED)

def retrieve_records():
    try:
        cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {scanner.table_name}")

        # Fetch rows from the result set
        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        # Clear the Treeview
        tree.delete(*tree.get_children())

        # Insert rows into the Treeview
        for row in rows:
            tree.insert("", "end", values=row)

        # Fetch any remaining result sets
        while cursor.nextset():
            cursor.fetchall()

        cursor.close()

    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", f"An error occurred while retrieving the records: {err}")




def search_records():
    try:
        search_term = search_entry.get().strip()
        if search_term:
            cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
            query = f"SELECT * FROM {scanner.table_name} WHERE data LIKE %s"
            cursor.execute(query, (f"%{search_term}%",))
            records = cursor.fetchall()

            tree.delete(*tree.get_children())

            for record in records:
                tree.insert("", "end", values=record)

            cursor.close()
            cursor = conn.cursor()  # Open a new cursor
            cursor.execute("SELECT 1")  # Execute a dummy query to consume any remaining unread result sets
            cursor.close()
        else:
            retrieve_records()
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", f"An error occurred while searching the records: {err}")

def on_closing():
    scanner.close()
    window.destroy()
 
# Function to sort the treeview records
def sort_records(column):
    records = tree.get_children("")
    records.sort(key=lambda item: tree.set(item, column))
    for index, item in enumerate(records):
        tree.move(item, '', index)
try:
    config = {
        'user': 'mukesh',
        'password': 'Mukesh@123',
        'host': 'localhost',
        'database': 'qr_demo',
        'raise_on_warnings': True
    }
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    print("Connected to the database.")
    
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print(f"An error occurred while creating the database connection: {err}")
    raise

scanner = QRCodeScanner(conn)

window = Tk()
window.title("QR Code Scanner")
window.geometry("800x600")
window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

# Configure styles
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("Treeview", font=('Arial', 10))
style.configure("TButton", font=('Arial', 12))
style.configure("TLabel", font=('Arial', 12))

# Create a frame for the buttons
button_frame = Frame(window)
button_frame.pack(side=TOP, padx=1, pady=10)

start_button = Button(button_frame, text="Start Scanning", command=start_scanning)
start_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

stop_button = Button(button_frame, text="Stop Scanning", command=stop_scanning, state=DISABLED)
stop_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=(5, 5), pady=5)

# Create a frame for the search elements
# search_frame = Frame(window)
# search_frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

search_label = Label(button_frame, text="Search:", font=('Arial', 12))
search_label.pack(side=LEFT, padx=(20, 5), pady=5)

search_entry = Entry(button_frame, font=('Arial', 12))
search_entry.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

search_button = Button(button_frame, text="Search", command=search_records, font=('Arial', 12))
search_button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5,  pady=5)

# Create a frame for the treeview
tree_frame = Frame(window)
tree_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)

tree = ttk.Treeview(tree_frame, columns=('ID', 'Data'), show='headings')
tree.column('ID', width=100, anchor="center")
tree.column('Data', width=600, anchor="w")
tree.heading('ID', text='ID', anchor="center", command=lambda: sort_records("ID"))
tree.heading('Data', text='Data', anchor="w", command=lambda: sort_records("Data"))
tree.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

tree_scroll = Scrollbar(tree_frame)
tree_scroll.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

tree.configure(yscrollcommand=tree_scroll.set)
tree_scroll.configure(command=tree.yview)

# Apply a custom font to the treeview headers
font_style = font.Font(family="Arial", size=12, weight="bold")
tree.tag_configure("custom_font", font=font_style)

for column in tree["columns"]:
    tree.heading(column, text=column, anchor="center")


retrieve_records()
window.mainloop()
```

I will be thankful if someone can provide solution for given problem.

Answer (score -2):

try this below

```
def retrieve_records():
    try:
        cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {scanner.table_name}")

        # Fetch rows from the result set
        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        # Clear the Treeview
        tree.delete(*tree.get_children())

        # Insert rows into the Treeview
        for row in rows:
            tree.insert("", "end", values=row)

        # Fetch any remaining result sets
        while cursor.nextset():
            cursor.fetchall()

        cursor.close()

    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", f"An error occurred while retrieving the records: {err}")


def search_records():
    try:
        search_term = search_entry.get().strip()
        if search_term:
            cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
            query = f"SELECT * FROM {scanner.table_name} WHERE data LIKE %s"
            cursor.execute(query, (f"%{search_term}%",))
            records = cursor.fetchall()

            tree.delete(*tree.get_children())

            for record in records:
                tree.insert("", "end", values=record)

            cursor.close()
            cursor = conn.cursor()  # Open a new cursor
            cursor.execute("SELECT 1")  # Execute a dummy query to consume any remaining unread result sets
            cursor.close()
        else:
            retrieve_records()
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", f"An error occurred while searching the records: {err}")








def stop_scanning():
    global scanning
    scanning = False
    start_button.configure(state=NORMAL)
    stop_button.configure(state=DISABLED)
```

Comment: Above code does not works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You've posted 9 answers so far over the last 24 hours, and most of them are either mostly code with no explanation, appear likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT), or both. A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. For answers where you have not used AI, keep in mind that providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* your code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.